# MySQL: How to get a record based on the position

Tags: mysql, count, sql-order-by, record

I have a random number - like 10 - and I need to get the 10th register of a recordset.

I do a LOOP with count + 1 until 10.

but if the random number is really big, maybe I need to do a big loop too.

There is an easy method - in performance - to get this record?

```
NAME | GROUP
Alan    A
Paul    B
John    A
Frank   A

SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE GROUP = A
```

Randon number is "2" then:

I need to find the 2nd record:

```
NAME | GROUP
John     A
```

tks
daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LIMIT with an OFFSET you can get just the second row from the resultset

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE GROUP = 'A' 
LIMIT 1,1
```

Except that queries will return data in an order they find easy, so you may want to order the results as well

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE 
WHERE GROUP = 'A' 
ORDER BY NAME
LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly, first, tks for your time to help me. I'm not an expert in mysql - then just to understand the logic - ok - With this I got record 2, but if I need to get record 1239? If its "LIMIT 2" to got 1239 would be "LIMIT 1239"... but why "Limit 1,1" ? tks a lot! :D

Comment: to get 1239 i put "Limit 1238,1" - got it! Why.. I don't know.. but - I understand the logic.. :D